# Something wrong login with firebase phone number?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Let see my code event want to login, i got something wrong because event cannot to be success, i don't know what is wrong, in case i've done to desc my problem at my code, so let see below

> code

```
var phoneNumber = myPhone.text;
    phoneNumber = '+62' + int.parse(phoneNumber).toString();
    _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
        verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential auth) async {
          phoneStatus.value = 'Auto retrieving verification code';
          debugPrint('step 1');
          //_authCredential = auth;
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(auth).then((value) async {
            if (value.user != null) {
              User user = value.user!;
              updateUserData(user);
              Get.offAll(Root());

              await getUserData(user.uid);
              // TODO: Save token if notification service is added.
              _saveDeviceToken(user.uid);

              //onAuthenticationSuccessful();
            } else {
              phoneStatus.value = 'Invalid code/invalid authentication';
            }
          }).catchError((error) {
            phoneStatus.value = 'Something has gone wrong, please try later.';
          });
          debugPrint('step 3 : ' + phoneStatus.string);
          // if (phoneStatus.toString() == 'Authentication successful') {
          //   Get.offAll(Root());
          // }
          Get.snackbar('Phone Login', phoneStatus.toString(),
              snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
              colorText: Colors.white,
              backgroundColor: kPrimary);
        },
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate SHA1 Fingerprint and needed to be add inside firebase console for your project  and registered package name.

this link will help you for this.
https://buildcoding.com/create-and-add-sha1-fingerprint-to-firebase-project/

Comment: tq sir it's solve